# Windows key shortcuts

Tags: windows, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Is there a plugin that will give me the same directional key shortcuts as with Windows 7? Basically, if you hold the windows key and tap a direction, the active window changes to a side, top, bottom of full-screen orientation - very useful when stacking windows side by side. I really miss this function as well as a few others and would love to use them in Ubuntu.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This shortcuts are default in Ubuntu 14.04.

But anyway you can install `compizConfig settings manager` and look at the section: `Window Management > Grid`. There you can define the shortcuts you want for such actions.